# Android: input field does not fire event when hitting 'next' on keyboard

Tags: android, android-browser, dom-events

I have multiple input fields on a html page optimized for Android.

The problem is that the event "onchange" is not always triggered when 'next' is clicked on the virtual keyboard.

To me this seems to be a similar to issue 7459 of the Android browser:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7459

How can I circumvent or compensate this issue? I need to calculate and refresh another input field in the function calc() after the value of any of the fields has been changed. If available even Android specific events or behaviours can be used.

Thanks, Holger

Comment: Did you see that it was fixed in Froyo (2.2)?  What OS are you using?

Comment: The problem does not show in the Android emulator. But I have seen it on a Samsung Tablet running 2.2 and users with 2.1 complained about it. Sometimes hitting 'next' does trigger the event onchange and sometimes the event is just ignored. The same page will run smoothly on the iPhone 3G, FireFox and IE.